# Create Record type that infers a generic based on the keys

Tags: typescript

I'm wanting to do something like this:

```
type PossibleKeys = "foo" | "bar" | "not-bar"; 

type SpecialRecord = Record<PossibleKeys, {
    key: PossibleKeys; // I want to make sure that this key matches the record key. 
    data: number; 
}> ; 



const myRecord = {
    foo: {
        key: "foo", // Should be ok
        data: 9, 
    }, 
    bar : {
        key: "not-bar", // Should error
        data: 10
    }
};
```

That is, I want to declare my `SpecialRecord` type such that it enforces that the key of the record matches the `key` property of the value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a **mapped object type**, and here's how you would do it:

```
type PossibleKeys = "foo" | "bar" | "not-bar"; 

type SpecialRecord = {
    [K in PossibleKeys ]: {
        key: K; 
        data: number; 
    }
}

const myRecord : SpecialRecord= {
    foo: {
        key: "foo", 
        data: 9, 
    }, 
    bar : {
        key: "not-bar", //Type '"not-bar"' is not assignable to type '"bar"'.(2322)

        data: 10
    }
};
```